# What can the EU do to prevent the circumventions of sanctions against Russia?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, sanctions

> The Russian economy appears more resilient than expected and the
> Russian military retains the capacity to destroy civilian
> infrastructure and military targets and terrorise the Ukrainian
> population. What is more, sanctioned goods are still finding their way
> to Russia and to the battlefield in Ukraine.
>
> If the sanctions are not working the way they ought to, it is because
> we are actively undermining them. A recently released report by
> Norway-based risk consultancy Corisk reveals how that is done.
>
> Its analysis of customs data from 12 EU countries, Norway, the UK, the
> US and Japan shows that the circumvention of export sanctions on
> Russia amounted to an astonishing 8 billion euros ($8.5bn) in 2022. AD
>
> Of the countries studied, Germany appears to be the largest exporter
> of sanctioned goods to Russia; the second largest is Lithuania. The
> two provide half of the Western goods Moscow should not have access
> to.

https://www.aljazeera.com/opinions/2023/6/5/sanctions-on-russia-may-not-be-working-we-now-know-why

I was reading this and I was wondering what are effective things the EU can do to prevent the sanctions of being circumvented. I was thinking punishing the German government, the German companies and other governments and companies for doing this would maybe work, but not be terribly effective, so I was wondering if there are effective measures that can be undertaken by the EU.

Comment: DW made an [interesting short documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7yofon22AM&ab_channel=DWDocumentary) about this topic about one month ago.

Answer (score 1):

The [European Commission already approved another sanctions package](https://www.rferl.org/a/eu-russia-sanctions-package-ukraine-war/32472199.html) that should also include entities that are involved in circumventing previous sanctions (my emphasis):

> The European Council has adopted the 11th package of sanctions against
> Russia over its invasion of Ukraine, extending some restrictions and
> adding dozens of new entities around the world to its list as it tries
> to stop other countries and companies from circumventing previously
> imposed measures.
>
> (..)
>
> The council said it added to its sanctions list 87 new entities that
> the EU says are "directly supporting Russia's military and industrial
> complex in its war of aggression against Ukraine." **Those companies,
> the bloc said, are registered in China, Uzbekistan, the United Arab
> Emirates, Syria, and Armenia.**